# SQL Server will read all the records for sub query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT [coit_id] AS commodity
          ,[sist_id]
          ,[cost_modified_date]
          ,[cost_timestamp]
    FROM [Cargo_Ver_3_0_33].[dbo].[Commodity_State]) 
WHERE 
    commodity > 15
```

Does SQL read all records first while checking condition?

Comment: sorry query pasted minstakely please read below line also

Comment: why are you using a subquery? it's not necessary

Comment: That is not deterministic because the sql engine works based on statistics and it develops a query plan and execute the query based on that query plan.

Comment: If this is SQL Server and you want to find out, press CTRL-L to see the query plan. You'll see that the commodity filter is indeed applied directly to the table, not after the subquery is run.

Comment: In SQL, you describe *what you want*, not *how to do it*, and then (hope that) the optimizer will find the best way to produce that result.

Answer (score 0):

No need to do sub query here, it is going to be more costly. The below query will provide the same results. In your above example the SQL engine will build the sub select list first and then execute the outer query, but you are not accomplishing anything unique that requires the sub query.

```
    SELECT 
    [coit_id] AS commodity,
    [sist_id],
    [cost_modified_date],
    [cost_timestamp],
    FROM [Cargo_Ver_3_0_33].[dbo].[Commodity_State]  WHERE commodity > 15;
```

Comment: You forgot the '[coit_id] AS commodity' field.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good article about "[How SQL Server executes a query](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/630346/Understanding-how-SQL-Server-executes%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B-a-query)".

You can read and see that at first `Data caches` Then `Query Execution` calls that do some seeking and other operations.